# Timestamp redquerybuilder

Tags: redquerybuilder

Timestamp is not working RedQueryBuilder
.getting error unknown datatype

Object { e: "Could not find type 'timestamp'", "__gwt$backingJsError": Error }
​
"__gwt$backingJsError": Error: Could not find type 'timestamp'

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the "timestamp" data type in your meta data?

I'm the original author of RedQueryBuilder and I'm sad to say I think it is pretty much dead.

Cheers

Sam